# Qt .pro file get Qtkit name

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt project that is dependent on other 3rd party libraries that I've compiled from source. When compiling these 3rd party libraries I specify what Qt kit to use for compiling (as these 3rd party libs are dependent on Qt)

For example, these 3rd party libs might have been compiled using Qt5.9.2_x64_msvc2015, they also might have been compiled using Qt5.7.2_x64_msvc2013.

So in the project I'm developing, if I want to compile using the Qt5.9.2_x64_msvc2015 kit, then I would like the project to automatically switch the `LIBS` and `INCLUDEPATH` to the 3rd party libraries that I compiled with the same Qt kit.

I know I can use the `QT_MAJOR_VERSION`, `QT_MINOR_VERSION`, and `QT_PATCH_VERSION` to check what "version" of the qt kit I'm using, but how could I get in the .pro file if the kit being used is `x64` vs `x86` as well as `msvc2013` vs `msvc2015`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks  like I figured it out on my own. The term I was looking for was stored in the `CONFIG` variable.

if you do a `message($$CONFIG)`, you will see a whole bunch of stuff printed, but the one you're looking for is the `win32-msvc2013` or `win32-msvc2015` items.

So a check on this would look something like the following:

```
CONFIG("win32-msvc2013") {
    # do something specific to the msvc2013 kit
}
CONFIG("win32-msvc2015") {
    # do something else specific to the msvc2015 kit
}
```